# Tensorflow & Tensorflow object detection version compatibility

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am relatively new to programming. A tutorial I am following needs me to install the following packages:

```
tensorflow
tensorflow-object-detection-api==0.1.1
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
pandas
matplotlib
```

I installed them all in a virtual environment. However, I am not sure if the tensorflow latest version and the tensorflow-object-detection-api at version 0.1.1 are compatible.

I tried to run my program, but got the following error:

```
from object_detection.core import keypoint_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you should manually install from the github. and the repository link is
[Clone it on your system](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)